# I'm Lucio trying to recover the access to my account

Tags: support, user-accounts, duplicate-accounts, merge

Users:

- Normal: https://askubuntu.com/users/62483/lucio
- New: https://askubuntu.com/users/214262/user214262

After log out yesterday, when I tried to login again, due to strange reason, StackExchange has created a *new* account instead of login with the *normal* one.

I am using MyOpenID as the credential, but after this error (and knowing that it will be off shortly) I want to access using only my email.

Could someone delete the new one, and do something so I can recover my normal account?

Thanks

Comment: Wait.. What happened? Did you log into your Lucio account with your email or do you not have access to Lucio because MyOpenID is now closed?

Comment: If you didn't link another account apart MyOpenID... UPS!

Comment: I couldn't access with my email. MyOpenId didn't recognized *Lucio*, so it has created a second account (this one). Lucio exists only on Chat rooms (someone could explain why? Nevermind, it does not matter). **Could someone please recover Lucio?!**

Comment: See [myOpenID no longer supported; add alternative login method to your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442).

Answer (score 4):

The user lucio has the following OpenID logins configured:

[image]

Just use one of them to login, and [initiate the account merger yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).

Comment: Thanks! The reason was that I've changed the email, but thanks to the *Wordpress* account I recover the account. Many thanks!

Comment: PS: it would be useful to delete the obsolete `user214262` user. I don't want to login 'cause maybe I scrub it all again :-)